# How to disable master grid rowSelect while detail grid is loading in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a Master detail jqGrid which is working perfectly. The detail grid is being populated based on a cellvalue from the Master grid's selected row and an ajax call to an API i.e. `datatype: 'json'` and `url: 'http://myServiceurl/rowdata.id'`.

However, for certain Master rows the data set for the detail row so it's taking a few moments to load and the detail grid shows "Loading...". This is perfectly fine, until the user clicks a different row in the master grid while the detail grid is still "Loading...". This is a problem because I am loading some additional info on the detail grid's `caption` and while the data on the detail grid is still loading from previous rowSelect the detail grid's caption changes to reflect the current master grid's row selected but the actual table data is from the previous row selected in the master grid.

The master-detail grid is coded as below `jqgrid` option on the master grid-

```
onSelectRow: function(ids) {      //load the detail table tabDiv2
                $("#"+divToHide).show();    //show the hidden div for detail grid
                var rowdata = jQuery("#"+tabDiv).getRowData(ids);
                    jQuery("#"+tabDiv2).jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:useruri+"/"+rowdata.dbsid,
                                                           datatype: 'json'})
                    jQuery("#"+tabDiv2).jqGrid('setCaption',"Database Name:&nbsp;"+rowdata.dbname)
                    .trigger('reloadGrid');
                },
```

One solution I could imagine is using `beforeSelectRow` option on the master grid and check if the detail grid is still being loaded-

```
beforeSelectRow: function(){
       //check if detail grid is fully loaded <--
       //if fully loaded return true else return false
}
```

How do I check if the detail grid is fully loaded? I have tried `$("#"+tabDiv2)[0].grid` but it always returns true since I think the overall DOM element of the grid gets loaded before the data gets loaded inside of it. I have tried checking number of records using `$("#"+tabDiv2).getGridParam("records")` but this may not always work, since the detail grid not having any row for a selected master grid row is a valid scenario and will permanently disable rowSelect on the master grid. What else are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid set `$("#"+tabDiv2)[0].grid.hDiv.loading` to `true` during Ajax request to load the grid is pending. Then you can use just the following callback in the first grid

```
beforeSelectRow: function () {
    var detailGrid = $("#"+tabDiv2)[0];
    return detailGrid != null && detailGrid.grid != null && detailGrid.grid.hDiv.loading ?
        false : true;
}
```

Comment: That's a great way of doing it with less code. Thanks again @Oleg!

Comment: a new issue showed up. I am now using `loadError: function (jqXHR){ $('#alertDiv'.show(); }` to show an alert (which is basically a `<div>` of Bootstrap Alert type), if there's no data or an error in the detail grid. When I do that your code above stops working. Not entirely sure why but the answer I posted below still works with a minor modification.

Comment: @Annjawn: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? I develop free jqGrid fork starting with the end of 2014. It contains default implementation of `loadError`, which displays the error in the "error div" over the grid body. In any way, `grid.hDiv.loading` should be **automatically** (by jqGrid) set to false after call of `loadError`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, I'll find out the version (there's quite a few plugins I use can't remember all the version). I'll play around with your suggestion a bit coz I like the approach. It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the code below. However, based on my question on how to do it using `beforeSelectRow`, I prefer @Oleg's answer better. But just in case, below is another way of doing it.

By setting `setgridparam` on master grid `beforeRequest` and `loadcomplete` of detail grid.

```
onSelectRow: function(ids) {      //load the detail table tabDiv2
                $("#"+divToHide).show();    //show the hidden div for detail grid
                var rowdata = jQuery("#"+tabDiv).getRowData(ids);
                    jQuery("#"+tabDiv2).jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:useruri+"/"+rowdata.dbsid,
                                                           datatype: 'json',
                                                           beforeRequest: function(){
                                                             jQuery("#"+tabDiv).jqGrid('setGridParam',{
                                                                          beforeSelectRow: function(){
                                                                            return false;
                                                                          }
                                                             })
                                                           },
                                                         loadComplete:function(){
                                                           jQuery("#"+tabDiv).jqGrid('setGridParam',{
                                                                        beforeSelectRow: function(){
                                                                          return true;
                                                                        }
                                                           })
                                                         }
                                                       })
                    jQuery("#"+tabDiv2).jqGrid('setCaption',"Database Name:&nbsp;"+rowdata.dbname)
                    .trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
```